# Cannot implement lazy high chart receiving errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I am trying to implement lazy high charts using the following github site [GitHub](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts) I have done the following steps

- rails plugin install git://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts.git
- @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
      f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
    end
- <%= javascript_include_tag 'highcharts' %>
- <%= high_chart("my_id", @h) %>

What is confusing is I reach the point where it tells you to put the code into the controller but doesn't tell you where exactly. So I tried doing some of the following and these were the results

1)

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
   access_control do
    actions :index do
      allow :Admin
    end
  end

 def index
   @title = "Welcome to Dashboard"
    before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index]
  @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
    f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
        end
     end
    end
```

Outcome =

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant DashboardController::LazyHighCharts
```

2)

```
 class DashboardController::LazyHighCharts < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:index]
  @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
    f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
  end
   access_control do
    actions :index do
      allow :Admin
    end
  end

  def index
   @title = "Welcome to Dashboard"
  end
end
```

**View**

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.dataTables.min', 'datatable', 'jquery.dataTables.columnFilter'%>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'demo_table', 'jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom' %> 
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'highcharts'
    <div class="head">
        <h1>Welcome to Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="um rollover" id="um"><a><center><%= link_to image_tag("User.png", :alt => "User Management", :height => "100"), usermanagement_path %></center><br /><center>User Management</center><br /></a></div>
    <div class="pm rollover" id="pm"><a><center><%= link_to image_tag("Project.png", :alt => "Project Management", :height => "100"), projects_path %></center><br /><center>Project Management</center><br /></a></div>
    <div class="ts rollover" id="ts"><a><center><%= link_to image_tag("Timesheet.png", :alt => "Timesheets", :height => "100"), timesheet_path %></center><br /><center>Timesheets</center><br /></a></div>
    <div class="crm rollover" id="crm"><a><center><%= link_to image_tag("Customer.png", :alt => "Customer Relation Management", :height => "100"), crm_path %></center><br /><center>Customer Relation Management</center><br /></a></div>
    </div>

<%= high_chart("my_id", @h) %>
```

Outcome =

```
 LoadError in DashboardController#index

Expected c:/Users/patterd/documenTS/PadOnRails/app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb to define DashboardController
```

I tried these both ways and recieved different errors. I am still new to ror and javascript, so this may seem fairly easy to the you. Is there any suggestion or any advice where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is this code block:

```
@h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
    f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
end
```

Should be inside a controller action.

```
def index
  @h = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.series(:name=>'John', :data=>[3, 20, 3, 5, 4, 10, 12 ,3, 5,6,7,7,80,9,9])
    f.series(:name=>'Jane', :data=> [1, 3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4,-46,7,8,8,9,9,0,0,9] )
  end
end
```

Also I'd recommend installing it by adding the gem to your Gemfile instead of the plugin installation method.

```
gem 'lazy_high_charts'
```

Install gems:

```
bundle install
```

Install highcharts:

```
rails g lazy_high_charts:install
```

Don't forget this gem also requires jquery, so add the following to your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then install:

```
bundle
```

Then create the javascript:

```
rails g jquery:install
```

I have created a sample app, you can see it here: https://github.com/Gazler/Highcharts-rails-example

Comment: Yeah i realised that, that from the two examples I provided to you they were the same

Comment: Your code still isn't inside an action in the controller.  I have created a samply github app that you can look at/clone which works, you can check it out here: https://github.com/Gazler/Highcharts-rails-example  Hopefully that will clear up what I mean.  Look at the file app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb

Comment: I do have jquery rails in my gemfile already, about to try the gem 'lazy_high_charts git command, I did encounter a problem with this but I do not remember what it was will post the error in a moment. Thank you for responding

Comment: I checked out your github and there only seems to be a index.html.erb file

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, I was in the views folder when I pushed it up!  Check it out now and you will have a full app.  :)

Comment: @Gazler let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2657/discussion-between-user532339-and-gazler)

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem..  The chart was not being shown in the page

Controller code was ok
Page code was ok

But the hight charts installation didn't include the JS in the app/assets/application.js

if you face this problem, include the following code in  app/assets/application.js

//= require highcharts/highcharts
//= require highcharts/highcharts-more
//= require highcharts/highstock